# Correspondence between a set of 3D model points and their image projections

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a set of 3-d points and some images with the projections of these points. I also have the focal length of the camera and the principal point of the images with the projections (resulting from previously done camera calibration).

Is there any way to, given these parameters, find the automatic correspondence between the 3-d points and the image projections? I've looked through some OpenCV documentation but I didn't find anything suitable until now. I'm looking for a method that does the automatic labelling of the projections and thus the correspondence between them and the 3-d points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I *think* you mean to say that you have the intrinsic calibration of the camera, but not its location and attitude with respect to the scene (the "extrinsic" part of the calibration).

This problem does not have a unique solution for a general 3d point cloud if all you have is one image: just notice that the image does not change if you move the 3d points anywhere along the rays projecting them into the camera.

If have one or more images, you know everything about the 3D cloud of points (e.g. the points belong to an object of known shape and size, and are at known locations upon it), and you have matched them to their images, then it is a standard "camera resectioning" problem: you just solve for the camera extrinsic parameters that make the 3D points project onto their images.

If you have multiple images and you know that the scene is static while the camera is moving, and you can match "enough" 3d points to their images in each camera position, you can solve for the camera poses up to scale. You may want to start from David Nister's and/or Henrik Stewenius's papers on solvers for calibrated cameras, and then look into "bundle adjustment".

If you really want to learn about this (vast) subject, Zisserman and Hartley's [book](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/index.html) is as good as any. For code, look into [libmv](http://code.google.com/p/libmv/), [vxl](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/), and the [ceres](http://code.google.com/p/ceres-solver/) bundle adjuster.

Comment: I agree that the questions is not clear at all, but I would not say it is not possible. 
You can imagine some optimization method so that you find the correct extrinsic that will project the 3d points to the 2d points you have. Alternatively, it is possible for bundle adjustment to find the solution for you given a close enough estimate.

Comment: I said it is not possible for a general point cloud. I should have said "It is an ill-posed problem" instead, since it has infinite solutions, all defined up to a projectivity (hence oo^8 solutions).

Comment: I know the location of the points regarding a coordinate system that is defined in one of the points; the points are static and I have several images that result from a camera moving around the points. I'll look into the material you've suggested. Thank you.